# How to keep a loop within a loop from repeating an output in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops

Hey I'm just starting to learn Ruby over at codeacademy and I've come across an exercise that had an optional challenge that I can't get. The program takes a user defined string and "redacts" the words that the user wants "redacted". As you can see it turns the strings into arrays and then cycles through each value in the arrays (aka the individual words) and attempts to cross check the values of the original string with those of the words the user wants "redacted". The  original problem was to get it to redact one variable, the challenge was to get multiple words redacted. My problem is that when it goes through the checking loops it keeps returning values wrong. I understand what's wrong, sort of, the looping has to cross check values more than once and when it fails to '==' it keeps on printing out the word, but is there a way to fix this? Or is there a better angle to approach this?

```
puts "Give me what you've got" 
text = gets.chomp
text.downcase! 
puts "What words do you wish to redact"
redact = gets.chomp 
redact.downcase!
bye_words = redact.split(" ") 
words = text.split(" ")
words.each do |single_word| 
    bye_words.each do |word_in_question| 
        if word_in_question == single_word 
            print "REDACTED "
        else 
            print single_word + " "
        end 
    end 
end
```

Comment: In the inner loop, just keep track of if you found a match or not. Then after the inner loop, if you found a match, print 'REDACTED', if not, print the word.

Comment: Can you explain how I would go about doing that? I imagine that involves some sort of use of a boolean...?

Comment: Sweet I figured out how to make that work and it's now working perfectly. Thanks

Comment: Great! If you use `include?` like suggested below (and it's a good idea), you're essentially doing the same thing, you're just using the built-in `include?` (which loops over the elements looking for a match) instead of writing the loop yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe just use [include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-include-3F) instead of another loop:

```
puts "Give me what you've got"
text = gets.chomp
text.downcase!
puts "What words do you wish to redact"
redact = gets.chomp
redact.downcase!
bye_words = redact.split(" ")
words = text.split(" ")

words.each do |single_word|
  if bye_words.include? single_word
    print "REDACTED "
  else
    print single_word + " "
  end
end
```

Or even [gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) but maybe that's cheating...?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? You dont have to loop through two different sets:

```
puts "Give me what you've got" 
text = gets.chomp
text.downcase! 
puts "What words do you wish to redact"
redact = gets.chomp 
redact.downcase!
bye_words = redact.split(" ") 
words = text.split(" ")
ouput_words = []
words.each do |single_word| 
    if bye_words.include?(single_word)
        ouput_words << "REDACTED"
    else
        ouput_words << single_word
    end
end

print ouput_words.join(" ") + "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to get (almost) what you need is using [`-`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-2D):

```
puts "Give me what you've got" 
text = gets.chomp
text.downcase! 
puts "What words do you wish to redact"
redact = gets.chomp 
redact.downcase!
bye_words = redact.split(" ") 
words = text.split(" ")

puts (words - bye_words).join(' ')
```

The problem is that the redacted words will simply be removed from the text (`'REDACTED'` will not be added).

For that requirement to be filled, you need to find if each word is `included?` in the `bye_words`. What can do to improve on the others' suggestions is to turn the list of `bye_words` to a `Set`.

```
require 'set'
puts "Give me what you've got" 
text = gets.chomp
text.downcase! 
puts "What words do you wish to redact"
redact = gets.chomp 
redact.downcase!
bye_words = Set.new(redact.split(" "))
words = text.split(" ")

puts words.map { |word| bye_words.include?(word) ? 'REDACTED':word }.join(' ')
```